# SOAP Method Max Item Number

Tags: python, soap, suds

I was wondering if there was a maximum limit to the number of items that could be received through a SOAP method, or if the server I'm communicating with just has a strange limit.

When using Python's framework Suds, I used a method called getRecords from a database of about 39,000 rows.  Unfortunately, when I actually get the results, I only get a list of about 250.  Of course, this is data for each row that is necessary for the system to work. I was just curious if the reason why I was being limited was based upon a limit set by SOAP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limit. It's just on the server side so that big queries wouldn't hinder the server's work.

Comment: Harsh. That puts my development at a standstill.  Thanks!